# Настройка сообщений валидации Codigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Можно ли сделать что то подобное? У меня есть 3 правила валидации(required,is_unique,matches).То есть если поля не заполнены вылезает одно общее сообщение "Заполните поля",далее если ввожу логин который уже есть в базе,то выдает сообщение "Логин существуе",но при этом если остальные полня не заполнены не вылазило сообщение "заполните поля".

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules(
                                'login', 'Login',
                                'required|is_unique[users.login]',
                                array(
                                    'is_unique'=>'%s already exists.'
                                )
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('retype_pass', 'Retype', 'required|matches[pass]');
```